# Nix openai python dev-environment build failure

Tags: python-3.x, development-environment, nix, openai-api

I am trying to make a python37 development environment containing the `openai` pypi package using nix.

This [question was originally on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NixOS/comments/jnai8x/python_devenv_build_error/), but I couldn't find an answer and the activity in the thread was very low.

using the tipps i got there and the language frameworks documentation i managed to come up with the following expressions:

default.nix:

```
with import<nixpkgs>{};
( let
    openai = pkgs.callPackage ./release.nix {
              inherit pkgs; 
              buildPythonPackage = pkgs.python37Packages.buildPythonPackage;
            };
  in pkgs.python37.buildEnv.override rec {
    extraLibs = [ pkgs.python37Packages.requests openai ];
  }
).env
```

release.nix

```
{ pkgs, buildPythonPackage }:

buildPythonPackage rec{
  pname="openai";
  version="0.2.6";

  src=fetchTarball{
    url="https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/2d/b3bc2aa663b2c376f073fd141e128ecfb47f3aff95ccee284a74d85a1ef8/openai-0.2.6.tar.gz";
    sha256="0cplrzfw3i6yxcd35ijfjkx9jbcvkvzn5jn5b8s657a8myhm6kav";
  };

  propagateBuildInputs = [ pkgs.python37Packages.requests ];
  doCheck=false;

  meta = { # only for testing the env right now
    homepage="...";
    description="...";
    license = "...";
    maintainers= [];
  };
}
```

however, this leaves me with the (i guess its pip-)error

```
Processing ./openai-0.2.6-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests>=2.20; python_version >= "3.0" (from openai==0.2.6) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests>=2.20; python_version >= "3.0" (from openai==0.2.6)
builder for '/nix/store/ncnga4fcxl15xyvv3f325f9g0q45mqvr-python3.7-openai-0.2.6.drv' failed with exit code 1
```

which surprises me, because `propagateBuildInputs = [ pkgs.python37Packages.requests ];` clearly states that the package `requests` (version 2.22.0 in nixpkgs) should be present at build time.

what am I misunderstanding about the `buildPythonPackage` function that prevents this from working?

Comment: Your build commands contains pip3 , python3 ?

Comment: I tried it with multiple versions; but the build commands should be set automatically by buildPythonPackage (to the version that i pass it); if i am understanding the function correctly...

Comment: Could this just be `propagateBuildInputs` != `propagatedBuildInputs`?

Comment: Can you try to create your own build script with all python3 and pip3 (Just replace where it is python -> pythn3 and pip -> pip3)?

Comment: also use sudo pip3 in the external script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `progagatedBuildInputs` to another name like `progagateBuildInputs` causes it to be ignored, so any dependencies it contains (i.e. `requests`) are not found. For example:

```
yubico-client/default.nix

  propagateBuildInputs = [ requests ];

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests<3.0,>=2.7 (from yubico-client==1.13.0) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests<3.0,>=2.7 (from yubico-client==1.13.0)

  propagatedBuildInputs = [ requests ];

$ nix-build -I nixpkgs=~/git/nixpkgs '<nixpkgs>' -k -A python37Packages.yubico-client
/nix/store/0yjz8smgmjr0006nmka6wliy01z8av7m-python3.7-yubico-client-1.13.0
```

Comment: thanks; that was it; of course it was that simple ^^;  i will give u the promised bounty in 23 hours when this is possible :)

Comment: @FabianSchneider thanks, it was so simple I was pretty sure someone would point to a place it was defined as a synonym, but since they didn't it was quick to test. :)